# Is there a specific function within Network Analysis - OD Cost Matrix that solves for connectivity issues?

Tags: arcgis-pro, geoprocessing, network-analyst, distance-matrix

I am calculating the distance between points along a network dataset of roads. However, I am running into issues as some of the points do not align along the road network. I have attached an example of a point within my dataset.

[image: point and network image]

I have been struggling and trying different things when sorting out the parameters of the OD Cost Matrix when I import my destinations and origins. Is it something that can be done there or would I have to manually edit each line so they connect to each point. Or is there something that is more automatic and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with python.

You can use a tool like Pandana to perform your network analysis. The function [pandana.network.Network.get_node_id()](https://udst.github.io/pandana/network.html#pandana.network.Network.get_node_ids) will find the closest starting point in your street network, within a given distance (of your choice).

Or if you prefer OSMNX, the equivalent function would be [osmnx.network.distance.nearest_edges()](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.distance.nearest_edges)